# I can't kill my session

Tags: php, session

I want to use `session_id()` as a reference when the visitor enters the photos attached to an advertisement. When visitors clicked finish I want to kill the session so that user can add a new ad (with new id), but how hard I try, it's the original `session_id` (): is shown.

It seems to kill the session where I want but when I reload the page the same old session id back. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION['ad'] = session_id();

// Do what ever and then kill the session

session_unset();
session_destroy();
$_SESSION = array();
?>
```

Comment: You using session_start(); and session_destroy(); in same page ?

Comment: Try reordering of statements: `$_SESSION = array(); session_destroy();`

Comment: `session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE ? $_SESSION = array() && session_unset() && session_destroy() : null`

Comment: Yes, I have them both at same page a I've ben told to always have session_start(); in top of index (but I just tried to not have it on the "killing page" but that did not help). ... Reordering did not help either.

Comment: there is any cookie store for session?

Comment: I do not know what your lines does @DanFromGermany but I tried it as well but it did not help .... no other cookie is used

Comment: you can use `session_regenerate_id(true)` to change the session id. But you will hay to remove all sessions variables by your self.

Comment: Thank you @Perry but even using the example for session_regenerate_id() on php.net I get the same id for both old and new ... this is so strange!

Comment: I fear the line `$_SESSION = array();` won't help: it only change where the `$_SESSION` points. I don't think it reset the "real" `$_SESSION` variable.

Comment: Try `unset($_SESSION['ad']);`

Comment: So I finally got it to work with session_regenerate_id. The biggest problem for me was a menu script that I have purchased (http://css3menu.com/). 
If I had the menu before session_regenerate_id () in the code did not work session_regenerate_id ()